# how to call webbrowser from form2 c#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

i took two form (form1 & form2) in my program. in form1 i took a button & in form2 i took a webbrowser.

i want to run webbrowser on form2 by clicking on form1 button.

but my program not working.

Please help me, how to do this currently.

this is my program code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void progressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try 
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connect to Internet First","Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: We are going to need a little more information, how is it not working? What kind of behavior are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

First, in form1.designer, change this line of code:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser1;
```

to:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser1;
```

now, in form1 button_click:

```
    Form2 f = new Form2();
    f.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
    f.Show(this);
```

solution II:
In form1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f = new Form2();
    f.Url = "http://www.google.com";
    f.Show(this);
}
```

In form2:

```
public string Url { get; set; }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.webBrowser1.Navigate(this.Url);
    }
```

Comment: Can't make an omelette without breaking a few eggs. If you want to access a field from another class, it must be public (or at least protected) ! You could use a property to control setter access. public WebBrowser webBrowser1 { get; private set; }